# Tomcat login issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

It occurs that I have a problem configuring tomcat7 properly. After I 
figured that I couldn't log in, because none of the 4 available manager
roles are available by default I decided to add these user specifications
in the tomcat-users.xml file in the conf directory of tomcat:

```
< role rolename="manager-gui" />
< user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui" />
< role rolename="manager-script" />
< user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script" />
< role rolename="manager-jmx" />
< user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script" />
< role rolename="manager-status" />
< user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-status" />
```

Of course, these username and password combinations are merely examplary.
Also, I had shut down the server after I had saved the changes in the
tomcat-users file. Then I started up the server and opened the localhost
webpage using the corresponding http connector port(8000 in my case). For some
reason, I still wasn't able to access any parts of the welcome page. I clicked
manage app and had to enter username and password. I tried all username and password
combinations I had added in the tomcat-users.xml file, but everything just failed. Is there anyone who might know 
what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Okay, thank you but although there may have been spaces present between the < symbols and the roles in my post, that is not the case in my .xml file. Do you perhaps have a different suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add manager.xml in conf/[enginemane]/[hostname] with your localhost address(127.0.0.1)?

Check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html if you didn't or don't know how.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I have looked into it again and noticed that the server doesn't properly shut down using the shut down command in the bin directory. It says: Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME variable is defined. At least one of the environment variable is needed to run this program. I will also try adding the manager.xml ,but it seems likely that it has to do with a disfunctioning shutdown command in bin. When I restart the server after defining the roles and users I notice that all the saved changes are gone each time.